# Keep unique node with lowest value on second index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am working on a multi dimensional array in PHP. How is it possible to select unique values from 0 index of a nested array which has lowest value on index 1?

Below is my sample data array

```
$data = array (
    array(1, 9),
    array(1, 3),
    array(1, 5),
    array(9, 2),
    array(9, 7),
);
```

I am trying to get following array as a result

```
$result = array (
    array(1, 3),
    array(9, 2),
);
```

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614831/filter-array-for-unique-records-with-lowest-value

Comment: Yes I tried to rewrite to make it simple and clearer. Already requested to delete my old question.

Comment: Well do you have at least an approach or an idea? (Not a fan of the “me need, you make” philosophy over here …)

Comment: In what way are those arrays more unique than the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this could be to loop the array,  use the indexes of the arrays and compare the second value. If the stored second value is greater than the new value, then overwrite it.

```
$data = array (
    array(1, 9),
    array(1, 3),
    array(1, 5),
    array(9, 2),
    array(9, 7),
);

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    if (!isset($result[$d[0]])) {
        $result[$d[0]] = $d;
        continue;
    }
    if ($result[$d[0]][1] > $d[1]) {
        $result[$d[0]] = $d;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ciLFs)

Comment: Perfect! My approach was very similar. I was not able to write code. Can you please explain why you used isset() here. Many thanks!!!

Comment: To first check if there is already something on that index. If there is nothing, then set it to the first array and loop again using `continue`. The next time there is something on that index and you can retrieve it.

Comment: Genius! Now I'm laughing at my code. I was using a custom function here inside `foreach` loop with some non understandable logic. I greatly appreciate your help. Just curious is this approach still good when I have a big array?

Comment: @AZee looping solutions will be slower the larger the array is. Non looping solutions generally are slower on smaller arrays but usually faster as the array size grows.

Comment: I just tested with a larger array and it's giving 20 arrays as a result. Something is not right. https://3v4l.org/863W1

Comment: @Andreas What result would you expect from your test? Your [random](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) returns  a random from 0 - 20 inclusive so that are 21 possible random values for both the key and the value. Then for each key (0 -20) you take the minimum value where chances are after 5000 iterations that those will be zero. Resulting in 21 arrays where the keys are from 0 -20 and all the values will be 0.

Comment: I assume OP wants the subarray with the lowest [0] and lowest [1] where the opposing column has the lowest value if there are more than one equal. So as i see it the output should be two arrays always.

Comment: I read the question as `unique values from 0 index of a nested array` (in your test 0 -20) `which has lowest value on index 1`  (in your test 0 -20). But perhaps @AZee can clarify that part?

Comment: I just tested the other answers and it's 50/50. Half of the answers give two arrays and half give 20. And I asked for a clarification about the uniqueness in comments but I didn't get an answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes you are correct. I required unique values from 0 index which has lowest value on index 1. Your code works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array (
array(1, 9),
array(1, 3),
array(1, 5),
array(9, 2),
array(9, 7),
);

$result = [];
$lowest0 = null;
$lowest1 = null;

foreach($data as $row){
    if($lowest0 === null || $row[0] < $lowest0[0] || ($row[0] === $lowest0[0] && $row[1] < $lowest0[1]))
    {
        $lowest0 = $row;
    }

    if($lowest1 === null || $row[1] < $lowest1[1] || ($row[1] === $lowest1[1] && $row[0] < $lowest0[0]))
    {
        $lowest1 = $row;
    }
}

$result = [$lowest0,$lowest1];

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This returns [1,9] instead of [1,3] as OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Short and dirty:

```
$data = array (
    array(1, 9),
    array(1, 3),
    array(1, 5),
    array(9, 2),
    array(9, 7),
);

foreach ($data as $row) {
 ($row[1] < ($uniq[$row[0]][1] ?? INF)) and $uniq[$row[0]] = $row;
}

var_dump($uniq);
```

Pass resulting array through `array_values` if re-indexing from 0 is important to you

Comment: Black magic :-) Appends row or overwrites old one in unique list if it is not there or if second column value in row is smaller than that in the list already by using short-circuit and operator which helps to avoid IF conditions - a plus if you are tired of many IF-ELSEIF-ELSE hell :-)

Comment: Squeezed yet another bytes from code by using new null coalescing operator and infinity constant.

Comment: WOW!! Can you please recommend a good book? I didn't hear `short-circuit and operator` before. Your code is very interesting. Yes sometimes IF-ELSEIF-ELSEis tiring and looks boring. I generally go with a SWITCH. I would love to read more about your approach.

Comment: Switch is good and is almost _irreplaceable_ tool for a state machine. And, contrary to many beliefs,- `goto` is very useful - consider terminating distributed transaction between 10 servers in a hundred page's of source code - without goto you would be lost. "short-circuit" just means that part of statement was not evaluated because it wasn't needed - `0>1 and printf('cool');` - printf will not be called because first condition was FALSE. It's simple like that. Code more - read less,- that's my recommendation for training skills :-) HTH

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand it :-)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is as clear as mud, but it I made it as an example that it works without looping.</strike>

In short I use min and array_intersect(_key) to find where the minimum values are in the columns (with array_column).

```
//split out the two columns
$col0 = array_column($data, 0);
$col1 = array_column($data, 1);

// find minimum value in each
$min0 = min($col0);
$min1 = min($col1);

// find what keys this minimum value is in of each array
$mincol0 = array_intersect($col0, [$min0]);
$mincol1 = array_intersect($col1, [$min1]);

// use the previous and compare with minimum value of the other column
$result[] = $data[array_keys(array_intersect_key($col1, $mincol0),min(array_intersect_key($col1, $mincol0)))[0]];
$result[] = $data[array_keys(array_intersect_key($col0, $mincol1),min(array_intersect_key($col0, $mincol1)))[0]];

Var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/dgbDK

Since I apperantly missunderstood the question.
Here is another answer, still no need to loop the full array. That is just a waste of time.

Loop only unique column 0 values and find the minmum value in column 1 using array_intersect and array_intersect_key.

```
$col0 = array_column($data, 0);

foreach(array_unique($col0) as $item){
    $intersect = array_intersect($col0, [$item]);
    $res[] = min(array_intersect_key($data, $intersect));

}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/3UPQh

Comment: @AZee Updated answer

Comment: I liked your approach and it works great. Thank you very much.